Asus TUF F15 Ram Upgrade
My laptop is ASUS TUF F15 2022 model(FX507ZC)
System Specs :

Processor: 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12700H Processor 2.3 GHz (24M Cache, up to 4.7 GHz, 14 cores: 6 P-cores and 8 E-cores)
RAM : 16 GB (8x2) DDR5 4800Mhz

Now i need to upgrade the RAM. I am planning to upgrade to the max capacity.


But the problem is ASUS website says that max capacity is 32 GB whereas When I run the the command as mentioned in this solution
https://askubuntu.com/questions/961210/how-can-i-know-how-much-ram-can-i-upgrade-my-laptop
it shows 64 GB.
Which one should I trust, and which config should I buy.
My thoughts are like, if Max capacity is

64 GB , then buy a 32 GB and keep one 8 GB (40GB) , replace the 8 with 32 GB later
32 GB, then buy 2 x 16 GB


You will get better performance from 2x16GB sticks if your laptop really supports just 32GB max. Can you just return the memory and buy different sticks if it doesn't work? I would lean towards believing the ASUS website instead of the dmidecode report, because the BIOS could have a hard coded limit that does not get seen by dmidecode. Also do you really need 64GB of RAM? Having that much extra ram is a waste of money, it doesn't make anything faster.

@Romen I thought like upgrading to max capacity for the future. But like you said it would be better to go forward with 2 x 16 config. Thanks

@Romen My current ram is 4800Mhz , can I use 2 x 16 GB ram for 5600Mhz

I suspect dmidecode takes a simple approach and only inspects the processor info. Looking at the i7122700H datasheet, down in "Memory Specifications", you'd note the 64GB limitation of the CPU. But memory support is also limited by chipset and how much memory is supported in Slots Per Channel (SPC) and DIMMs Populated Per Channel (DPC).
There isn't anything available online, specific with your laptop, to figure out what chipset your laptop is built with. But, it's reasonable that ASUS specifications are likely more accurate.
Unless you're editing video, rendering 3D, or for some odd reason, running a server with a lot of VMs, there is little use (as Romen mentioned) of that much memory.
